# Conditional compilation to see if code runs in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm aware of all the arguments against conditional compilation in Java. In this specific case, I'd only want to have a small IF in order to be able to test whether the code runs in Eclipse or not. The reason for this is that when I override a View to use my special processing, Eclipse in some cases cannot compile the modified View and display it in the IDE (there are many cases resulting in this behavior but a specific one is when the code refers to a JNI library that Eclipse, obviously, cannot execute).

Right now I'm using

```
if (!Build.DEVICE.startsWith("generic"))
 // do something
```

and it works but I don't really like doing a string comparison every single time in an onDraw(), for instance. I'd need a simpler way, a cheaper condition to see if I'm in Eclipse and avoid some actions then.

Edit: To be clearer, I'm looking for a possible Java/Android/Eclipse equivalent of C#'s Component.DesignMode property.

Comment: What do you mean "In Eclipse"?  Your code doesn't run "in Eclipse".  Do you mean when the debugger is attached?

Comment: No, in the UI editor of Eclipse, eg. when I create a layout using a custom version of a TextView. The new, overridden code does run, the IDE interprets it and tries to display custom View classes as much as it can (although with many simplifications, for instance, shadow layer is not supported but instead of a hard error, I get a simple dismissible warning then).

Comment: Addendum: "Exception raised during rendering" is the usual error message you get in these cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best I could come up with so far is:

```
import android.os.Build;

public class IDE {
  private static IDE instance = null;
  protected boolean designMode = false;

  private IDE() {
    designMode = Build.DEVICE.startsWith("generic");
  }

  public static IDE getInstance() {
    if (instance == null)
      instance = new IDE();
    return instance;
  }

  public static boolean DesignMode() {
    return getInstance().designMode;
  }
}
```

This is a singleton class that encapsulates the check and can be queried as:

```
if (!IDE.DesignMode())
  // do something
```